# How to increase database find speed grails mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
class CountryInfo {
    ObjectId id
    long ipFrom
    long ipTo
    String countryCode
    String countryName
    String regionName
    String cityName
    static constraints = {
        countryName index:true
    }
 }
```

This above is may domain.

I already created an index on `countryName` but when I query to find it, I think it does not use index

For example in mongo shell

```
db.CountryInfo.find({countryName:"CANADA"}).limit(57000).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor countryName_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 57000,
    "nscannedObjects" : 57000,
    "nscanned" : 57000,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 57000,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 57000,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 3,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 2577,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "countryName" : [
            [
                "CANADA",
                "CANADA"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "User"
}
 db.CountryInfo.count()
1860189
```

but in grails it takes too much time.

I think grails is not using index. Any solution to increase find speed?

Comment: I think not. It's the optimizer decision if and which index to use, not grails. You can peek the log to verify that the query ran from grails uses the index, which I doubt is not. The cause to slowness is probably the fact you are returning and probably iterating 57K documents. You should use pagination with your query, which is translated in server to `skip`

Comment: Can you include an example of your Grails code with the slow query? The output from the `mongo` shell seems to be using an index as expected. As suggested in an earlier comment, the performance issue may actually be related to the number of documents you are retrieving (especially if you are iterating 57k objects in Grail).